# SQL Server 2012 copy data of table to another one (1 column extra in new one)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to copy the data of a table in another one, but the new table has an extra column where I want to add a static text `Table_Name`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into another_one(col1, col2, . . . , newcol)
    select col1, col2, . . . , 'newvalue'
    from atable;
```

This allows you to add whatever value you like to the new column or columns.

If the new table doesn't exist, then use `select into`:

```
select col1, col2, . . . , 'newvalue' as newcol
into another_one
from atable;
```